# Не передаются значения в функцию

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float x1, x2, eps;
    float res;
    x1=1.0;
    x2=3.0;
    eps=0.1;
    res = findRoot(x1, x2, eps);
    printf("%f", res);  //res: 34.000000
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

float findRoot(float a, float b, float epsilon) {
    printf("a: %f b: %f epsilon: %d", a, b, epsilon);  // a: 0.000000 b: 2.312500 epsilon: 0
    return b;
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему a != x1, b != x2, eps != epsilon?
И почему, если везде заменить float на double, то программа не компилируется - возникает ошибка

> error 2371 переопределение различные
> базовые

p.s. Си, VS 2013, файл имеет расширение ".с"

Comment: с чего вы взяли, что они не равны? очень даже равны. Разве что epsilon вы выводите неправильно

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, почему, например, я присваиваю переменной x1 значение 1.0 и передаю это значение в функцию, но оказывается, что а == 0 != x1? Кроме того, b = 2.312500, но return b возвращает 34.000000 ?..

Comment: проверил программу, правда сделал пару исправлений, она выводит правильно (в пределах разумного).

Comment: http://uloader.ru/hwJgcP/file.png

а вот что выводит у меня. Так не должно быть?

Comment: вот так http://ideone.com/iwfs4F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа написана некорректно. До ф-ции main должно существовать определение `findRoot`. Я сталкивался с чем-то подобным с библиотечными ф-циями, когда не делал соответствующий `include`. Сишный компилятор думал, что сигнатура ф-ции int'овая...

Comment: Первая ссылка из гугля на [SO][1]

Причина проблемы - "You are trying to call ... before they are declared or defined."

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424239/error-c2371-eb-redefinition-different-basic-types-why-c